# RXJava in android without RXAndoid lib?

Tags: android, functional-programming, rx-java, rx-android

So my company is very strict and tedious when it comes to bringing in new libraries. We do have RXJava though and I really want to use that in order to replace some of the async tasks that are a pita, and to make a really solid auto suggest  without firing off long network calls on every text change.

My question is this:

Given some code like this

```
final EditText etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.crew_search_box);

Observable<EditText> searchTextObservable = ViewObservable.text(editText);
```

Can I set my observable to accomplish this same thing WITHOUT using RXAndroid and only using RXJava?

I am new to RX so forgive me if this is really just an out-there question.

Comment: yes. RXAndroid is open source, so you can always check how they do it and try to do something similar.

Comment: Wait so you can bring in RXJava but not RXAndroid? Sounds like the company really understands the codes. You're marketable find another job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can!

First of all, since you're mentioning `ViewObservable`: it's no longer there when you update your dependencies. `ViewObservable` and `WidgetObservable` [have been moved](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/wiki#moved), for various reasons. The initial 1.x release of RxAndroid meant a major refactor in terms of what is in there compared to the 0.x releases. [You can read more about that here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/172).

If you don't want to add RxAndroid as a dependency (or [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)) for that matter, just refer to the implementation details of the classes you're interested in and copy that into your own project. There's probably no need to make any modifications, but of course making copies means that you don't get the benefits of improvements either.

All RxAndroid (and RxBinding) really does is expose a bunch of convenience methods and implementations relevant to Android (surprise, surprise) that makes the lives of many a little easier. No one is, however, forcing you to use them. You can maintain your own code that you're interested in in parallel. Not sure that makes a lot of sense, but hey, it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could always code review the parts of RxAndroid that you want and include only them.  To be honest RxAndroid will implement view observables better than you will on your own.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How is telling someone to look over RxAndroid and see what parts they need not an answer? I feel like it is incorrect to tell some one to reimplement rx bindings themselves when they have trouble figuring out if they can.   The accepted answer said same thing I did just with more words.